# Solving limit using both a substitution and L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: limits

While evaluating this limit to find a, b, and c; $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{axe^x-b\ln(1+x)+cxe^{-x}}{x^2\sin x}=2$$

I first substituted $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$ in the numerator, and then used L'Hôpital's Rule twice to get the expression $\frac{ae^x + ce^{-x}}{\cos x -x\sin x +\cos x}$. I also derived that a+c=b, and that a=c, from the numerators of the intervening functions.

But the values I got for $a,b$ and $c$ weren't correct. Am I not supposed to use the limit substitution and LHR simultaneously? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand numerator and denominator with MacLaurin. We get
$$\frac{x (a-b+c)+x^2 \left(a+\frac{b}{2}-c\right)+\frac{1}{6} x^3 (3 a-2 b+3 c)+O\left(x^4\right)}{x^3+O\left(x^4\right)}$$
As we know that the limit is $2$ the following must be true
$$
\begin{cases}
a-b+c=0\\
a+\frac{b}{2}-c=0\\
\frac{1}{6} (3 a-2 b+3 c)=2
\end{cases}
$$
Solve the system to get $a = 3, b = 12, c = 9$.

Comment: I got this too, but the answer says a=3, b=12, and c=9, which is obtained using expansion. How is that correct?

Comment: @HarryHolmes It's wrong substituting. I edited my answer. Now it works

Comment: So it's okay to substitute and simplify a part of the limit before using the L'Hôpital's Rule on the rest of it?